# Робот не использует ни одного файла Sitemap

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Яндекс и Гугл не используют sitemap.txt, хотя он открыт и указаны пути к нему в настройках вебмастера...

Может robots.txt блокирует, хотя вроде бы нет... не знаю в чем проблема...

http://am-em.ru/robots.txt

http://am-em.ru/sitemap.xml

Что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно в следствии того что там ошибка:
[Ссылка на результаты валидации сервисом Яндекс.Вебмастер](https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/sitemap/?tab=url&sitemapUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fam-em.ru%2Fsitemap.xml)

> Нет данных в теге loc, стр. 556

Comment: Спасибо! Я исправил ошибку. Теперь жду следующего сканирование. Возможно причина не только в этом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обязательно зарегистрируйтесь на вебмастере Яндекса и аналогичной службе у Гугла и привяжите к своей учетке ваш сайт, если вы еще этого не сделали, также я бы советовал добавить на сайт метрику.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем файле robots блокирован index с директивами **Disallow: /index.php + Disallow: /index.html + Disallow: /index** . Сайты построены внутри каталогов на вебсервере. Так же, как у вас есть папки на компьютере,в  которые вы добавляете файлы, вы делаете то же самое с вебсервером с помощью добавления файлов вашего сайта, включая HTML - страницы, изображения, скрипты, CSS и т.д. Для вашего сайта, вы будете иметь каждую веб-страницу в виде отдельного файла. Например, ваша страница "Контакты" может быть "contact.html". Ваш сайт будет состоять из этих документов .html. Иногда, когда кто-то идет на сай, они делают это без указания одного из этих конкретных файлов в адресе. Например: example ru. Этот URL включает в себя домен, но нет конкретного файла в списке. По умолчанию этот файл/страница в каталоге называется index.html - файл главной страницы. Поэтому я рекомендую вам открыть эти файлы для просмотра, путём удаления указанных директив.

Comment: это сделано, чтобы исключить дубликаты главной страницы

Comment: Этот файл не является дубликатом. Он обозначает содержание главной страницы при запросе доменного имени. И вы можете применять канонический url для определения важности страницы, по вашему выбору: только домен, или же домен с index. Справка Гугл:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru